# AutoHotkey's ControlClick and Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, click, autohotkey

I'm trying to send a click to a google chrome window but it keeps making the window active thus preventing me to do anything else on the computer.

This is what I'm using:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
ControlClick, x136 y400, My Window,,,, NA
```

The NA doesn't seem to work on chrome. Any suggestions how to get this to work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is rarely optimal to automate websites with AHK. You seem to know one or two things about HTML or JavaScript. In Chrome I recommend using [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo). By defining hotkeys ([access keys](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp)), AHK can still play a role (e.g. triggering functions).

Comment: Do you have to use Chrome? With the Internet Explorer you can usually write code that stays in the background. This isn't easy though. For a recommendation on what to do you should write what exactly you click on and why you want to click in the background in the first place.

Comment: I'm just goofing around with a single player flash game. Would AHK's NA option work with IE?

Comment: @unska - no, it wouldn't. What you can do with the IE is to control it as a [COM object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lr4AVCS6y0g). This works great for normal browser interaction, but will probably not work if the action takes place within a flash window. For flash it might be easier to run the whole traffic through a proxy like proxomitron and watch what happens if you click. Then you can try to simulate the click with tools like curl. Highly complicated stuff, probably not worth doing it.

Comment: @576i But still fun doing it ;) In my experience, most flash games use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which are much harder to intercept (e.g. Proxomitron can't). WireShark and its CLI tool tshark on the other hand often get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Low tech solution is to just save and restore the active window. It will flicker but should work.

```
Me := WinExist("A")
ControlSend...
WinActivate %Me%
```